# Removing the “ - “ from input file

Tags: shell, unix, sql-loader, controlfile

The input is -> -747585959
And being loaded as -747585959
I just want it to be loaded as 747585959.
Used sql*loader for the data loading process.

The “ - “ is the first column and it has “ - “ for all the rows.

Comment: Maybe `sed 's/^-//' inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: Please show your control file.  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do this for that column in the control file, which will in effect skip the first character, the dash.

```
...
,inputdata    NULLIF(inputdata=BLANKS) "SUBSTR(:inputdata, 2)"
...
```